# Load and Save (csv format) a part large data CSV with spring boot spring batch

Tags: spring-boot

I would like to know if there is a way to load a large data in csv format, and then save only a part (ex: 50-100 lines) in csv format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is too large and you can't load everything at once, you could read the csv file line by line and get the data that you want.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i would like to know is it possible to do it with spring batch

Comment: Sure, it's possible. Take a look on this article.  I think it will help you out.
https://spring.io/guides/gs/batch-processing/

Answer (score 1):

CSV in reality is just text, you can turn your image into text byte but will not be usable as CSV.